# How can I delete manually calicoctl and iptables created by calico from my k3s setup

Tags: kubernetes, calico, k3s

I have a K3s setup with calico pods [`calico-node-` & `calico-kube-controllers-`] running. On uninstalling K3s, calico pods get deleted but I see that `calicoctl` and `iptables -S` commands still running and shows data.

I want to delete calico (including *calicoctl* and *Iptables* created by calico) completely. Which commands will help me to do so ?

**K3s uninstalltion command:** `/usr/local/bin/k3s-uninstall.sh` deletes all k3s pods including calico, but `calicoctl` and `iptables -S` still works.

**PS:** I already tried few things -

1. Command `kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/release-1.5/config/v1.5/calico.yaml` deletes the `calico-node-` but *`calico-kube-controller`* , *`calicoctl`* and *`iptables -S`* are still present
2. `Kubectl delete` commands in [this que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610641/how-to-delete-remove-calico-cni-from-my-kubernetes-cluster/53610810#53610810) also not working for me, after executing these two commands still *`calicoctl`* and *`iptables -S`* are present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Deleting calico-Iptables:**

Use [calico-policy](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/hack/remove-calico-policy/remove-calico-policy.sh) and add below lines at the end of script:

```
echo "Flush remaining calico iptables"
iptables-save | grep -i cali | iptables -F

echo "Delete remaining calico iptables"
iptables-save | grep -i cali | iptables -X
```

This will delete all calico iptables when you check with `iptables -S`

**Note:** Run this script only after uninstalling K3S.

**Deleting calicoctl:**

Simply run `sudo rm $(which calicoctl)` command, it will find and delete the calicoctl.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you will find a dedicated script](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/hack/remove-calico-policy/remove-calico-policy.sh) that will remove whole calico policy. Everything you need should be in the script.

Edit:
completely guide you can find [here](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/hack/remove-calico-policy/remove-policy.md)

Comment: Mikolaj-:: while running this script "sh remove-calico-policy.sh" the script goes in sleeping stage and didnt come out of that. the last line sleeping... it get stuck

Comment: Also calico-node-xxx pods and calicoctl still present after running this script

Comment: Where did you run this script? Note, that you need to run it on the node. This `sleep` at the end is fine, so DaemonSet doesn't die. It works as expected. I have edited the answer and send you completely guide to remove whole calico policy.

Comment: The link have changed to https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/calico/hack/remove-calico-policy/remove-calico-policy.sh and https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/tree/master/calico/hack/remove-calico-policy; respectively.